# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ then is it true that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. in $\Omega$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

> If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ then is it true that  $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. in $\Omega$? Or is it just true for a subsequence? And why?(Here $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$)

I have seen similar result for just $L^1$ without a proof. I have no clue about it when we replace it by $L^1_{loc}.$ Can somebody please help me to understand it?

Comment: what does convergence in $L^1_{loc}$ mean in your case?

Comment: For any compact set $K$ in $\Omega, \int_K |f_n | \rightarrow \int_K |f|$

Comment: I assumed that you mean convergence in $\int_K |f_n-f| \to 0$ in my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is just true along a subsequence.

Take a countable compact exhaustion $K_i, i\in\mathbb N$ of $\Omega$
with $K_i\subset K_{i+1}$.

On $K_1$ there is a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges a.e. on $K_1$, see, e.g.
[$L^1$ convergence gives a pointwise convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714744/l1-convergence-gives-a-pointwise-convergent-subsequence/716328)

Now you can apply the same argument to $K_2$ and the resulting subsequence of $K_1$,
so you have a subsequence of a subsequence that converges pointwise a.e. on $K_2$.

You can repeat this argument, and in the end you can choose a diagonal sequence out of these subsequences. Those converge pointwise a.e. on all $K_i$, and hence a.e. on $\Omega$.

Comment: You can give a counter-example : the typewriter sequence $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{n} \ 1_{\textstyle x \in \phi([\frac{n}{\pi}, \frac{n}{\pi}+1/n])}$$ where $\phi$ reduces an interval $[a,b]$ modulo $1$. This sequence doesn't converge pointwise for any $x \in [0,1)$